# can we get Sms delivery report in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, sms

i am successfully send Sms through my application,but i am unable to check is message sent or not.means any kind of delivery report by which my application get to know that Sms has Successfully reached to the desired location.

there were So many condition in which Sms Sending code run Successfully but message didn't send as if device balance is negative etc.
so how to  catch these events when sending Sms.

Comment: AFAIK we can't get SMS/MMS delivery report.

Comment: I am also lock with the same issue :(.is there any option to read the delivery reports in blackberry ?

Answer (score 0):

No you can't access the SMS delivery report from your application. For more info see this [discussion](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/i-want-help-from-send-sms-and-get-delivery-report-code/m-p/466706#M93404).